# How to reset root password of fedora 20 ...please answer in step wise

Tags: fedora

How to reset root password of fedora 20 
Please explain it stepwise because I am having difficulties

Comment: I take it your not logged in as root?

Comment: please edit your question and write your now state

Answer (score 0):

- If you know the password:

`su - ; passwd`

- If you have sudo :

`sudo passwd root`

- If you do not know the password but have physical access:

  Boot from recovery cd/usb

  mount /path/to/mount/with/etc

  i.e. mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

  vi /mnt/etc/shadow

  remove everything between the 2nd and 3rd colons.

  i.e. root:Ep6mckrOLChF.:10063:0:99999:7:::   becomes root::10063:0:99999:7:::

  reboot
- In newer fedora and maybe even F20 you can simply interrupt grub

Add init=/bin/bash to the end of the kernel line.

At the prompt run passwd

touch /.autorelabel (if you have SELinux) 
reboot